# How get latitude and longitude from an Android listview and put it in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, listview

I'm new to Android programming, In my mind i need an app that get latitude and longitude of a person from an embed csv file  then showing this in a listview. there is no problem so far. The point is that when user clicked on a row of listview, The app show him or her the Coordinates of that latitude and longitude in google map. how can i implement this?
ton of Thanks!

Comment: latitude and longitude from a listview ? What is this ? Is your list view is moving somewhere like berlin to mascow ? Your title is misleading . Edit it with proper problem you are facing .

Comment: Edit your question add the Activity or Fragment where there is your  ListView!

Comment: csv file contain a list of persons with latitude and longitude of them. i need to open it as a Coordinates in google maps when someone clicked it in listview

Comment: What you did till now? do you add the Google Maps code to your app? or just show the list. Add more info so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your latitude and longitude in a string and then use

```
String url1 = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=" + strLatLong;

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse(url1)); startActivity(intent);
```

It will open the location in google maps.